# Tkinter Entry Widget Not Displaying with .pack function

Tags: python, tkinter

**Disclaimer:** This is my first question on here so my apologize if the formatting is not proper. I am also completely new to tkinter and a relative beginner when it comes to Python.

I am trying to learn how the Entry widget works in tkinter but when I use the .pack nothing displays. When I use the .grid function it works!! I am following an online tutorial but I'm sure I am missing something simple so please let me know. Here is the dummy code I have been using to test:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

test = Entry(root)
test.pack

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```test.pack()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.pack` is a function. To call a function, you need to provide `()`. Without that, you are simply referencing the function

```
test.pack()
```

Comment: Wow that was an oversight. Thank you